# How to extract the timestamps whenever an e.g. categorical pandas time series changes state

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I recently had the problem where a pandas time series contained a signal that could take several states, and I was interested in the start and end timestamps of each state so that I could construct timeslots for each event. The input signal was a Pandas Series with a Timestamp index, and values could either be integers (e.g. numerical representation of a category) or NaN. For NaN, I could assume that there had been no state change since the last state (`ffill` would basically fix this) and that the state change happened exactly when it was logged (so the plot actually ought to be a step chart, not linearly interpolated as illustrated below).

Since timeslots are defined by their start time and the end time, I am interested in a method that can extract the pairs of `(start time, end time)` for the timeslots illustrated at the bottom of the figure.

[image: Illustration of input signal and desired result]

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [2,2,2,1,2,np.nan,np.nan,1,3,3,1,1,np.nan,
        2,1,np.nan,3,3,3,2,3,np.nan,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,
        np.nan,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,np.nan,2,1]
s = pd.Series(data=data, index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', freq='S', periods=40))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is the method I came up with. If anyone has a more efficient or elegant approach, please share.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the example Pandas Time Series
data = [2,2,2,1,2,np.nan,np.nan,1,3,3,1,1,np.nan,2,1,np.nan,3,3,3,2,3,np.nan,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,np.nan,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,np.nan,2,1]
dt = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', freq='S', periods=40)
s = pd.Series(data=data, index=dt)

# Drop NAN and calculate the state changes (not changing states returns 0)
s_diff = s.dropna().diff()

# Since 0 means no state change, remove them
s_diff = s_diff.replace(0,np.nan).dropna()

# Create a series that start with the time serie's initial condition, and then just the state change differences between the next states.
s_diff = pd.concat([s[:1], s_diff])

# We can now to a cumulative sum that starts on the initial value and adds the changes to find the actual states
s_states = s_diff.cumsum().astype(int)

# If the signal does not change in during the last timestamp, we need to ensure that we still get it.
s_states[s.index[-1]] = int(s[-1])

# Extract pairs of (start, end) timestamps for defining the timeslots. The .strftime method is only applied for readability. The following would probably be more useful:
# [(s_states.index[i], s_states.index[i+1] for i in range(len(s_states)-1)]
[(s_states.index[i].strftime('%M:%S'), s_states.index[i+1].strftime('%M:%S')) for i in range(len(s_states)-1)]
Out:
[('00:00', '00:03'),
 ('00:03', '00:04'),
 ('00:04', '00:07'),
 ('00:07', '00:08'),
 ('00:08', '00:10'),
 ('00:10', '00:13'),
 ('00:13', '00:14'),
 ('00:14', '00:16'),
 ('00:16', '00:19'),
 ('00:19', '00:20'),
 ('00:20', '00:23'),
 ('00:23', '00:24'),
 ('00:24', '00:25'),
 ('00:25', '00:26'),
 ('00:26', '00:28'),
 ('00:28', '00:32'),
 ('00:32', '00:33'),
 ('00:33', '00:34'),
 ('00:34', '00:35'),
 ('00:35', '00:36'),
 ('00:36', '00:39')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more compact method. We'll create a label for each group and then use `groupby` to determine where that group starts. To form these groups `ffill` to deal with NaN, take the difference and check where that's not 0 (i.e. it changes to any state). A cumsum of this Boolean Series forms the groups. Since the next group has to start when the previous group ends we  `shift` to get the end times.

```
gps = s.ffill().diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()

df = s.reset_index().groupby(gps.to_numpy()).agg(start=('index', 'min'))
df['stop'] = df['start'].shift(-1)
```

#### Output

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%M:%S')))
## If you want a list of tuples:
# [tuple(zip(df['start'].dt.strftime('%M:%S'), df['stop'].dt.strftime('%M:%S')))]

    start   stop
0   00:00  00:03
1   00:03  00:04
2   00:04  00:07
3   00:07  00:08
4   00:08  00:10
5   00:10  00:13
6   00:13  00:14
7   00:14  00:16
8   00:16  00:19
9   00:19  00:20
10  00:20  00:23
11  00:23  00:24
12  00:24  00:25
13  00:25  00:26
14  00:26  00:28
15  00:28  00:32
16  00:32  00:33
17  00:33  00:34
18  00:34  00:35
19  00:35  00:36
20  00:36  00:39
21  00:39    NaT   # Drop the last row if you don't want this
```

Comment: I will accept your answer I can verify that it is more efficient, but I get a ValueError when I try to run your second line caused by the .agg()-method. Using Pandas v.0.24.2.
`TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'`

Comment: Seems like the problem was my Pandas version, works fine with v0.25+. I'm still gonna accept my own answer, as it was faster during my %timeit performance test
Mine: `1.84 ms ± 54.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`
This one: `9 ms ± 246 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`
I tested it only on the dataset I provided in the example.